# savefig() causing ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a program who will :

1. Retrieve data from a csv file chosen by the user
2. Plot the data
3. Display the figure on the window
4. Allow the user to change the plot parameters (color, linestyle ...)
5. Save the plot in a directory chosen by the user in the PS format

Steps 1 to 4 are working just fine, but step 5 makes me feel like I've killed matplotlib ...

I'm using the same syntax I used on a previous version for saving, which worked fine :

```
        def savePlot(self):
    self.saveDirectory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, 'Chose where you want to save','/home',QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks)

    if self.plotParam==[]:
        plt.savefig(self.saveDirectory + "/" + "Untiltled.ps", dpi = 1200)

    else :
        plt.savefig(self.saveDirectory + "/" + "%s.ps" %self.plotParam[0],format = 'ps', dpi = 1200)
```

[Here](http://www.cjoint.com/c/GHijJbpEO1S) is a link to the full code, and [here](http://www.cjoint.com/c/GHijUyBS8zS) is the data file I'm using.

In this portion, self.plotParam is a list which is initially empty and contains the plot parameters if the user wants to change the default ones.

Here is the error log :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 141, in to_rgba
        rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/antoine/CERB/courbes/courbesv2.py", line 354, in savePlot
        plt.savefig(self.saveDirectory + "/" + "essai.ps", dpi = 1200)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 697, in savefig
        res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1573, in savefig
        self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 222, in print_figure
        FigureCanvasAgg.print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2252, in print_figure
**kwargs)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_ps.py", line 957, in print_ps
        return self._print_ps(outfile, 'ps', *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_ps.py", line 988, in _print_ps
**kwargs)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_ps.py", line 1078, in _print_figure
        self.figure.draw(renderer)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
        draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1144, in draw
renderer, self, dsu, self.suppressComposite)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 139, in _draw_list_compositing_images
        a.draw(renderer)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
        draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2426, in draw
        mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, dsu)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 139, in _draw_list_compositing_images
        a.draw(renderer)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
        draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 354, in draw
        self._offset_position)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_ps.py", line 607, in draw_path_collection
offset_position)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 309, in draw_path_collection
antialiaseds, urls, offset_position):
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 497, in _iter_collection
        gc0.set_foreground(fg)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1027, in set_foreground
        self._rgb = colors.to_rgba(fg)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 143, in to_rgba
        rgba = _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
      File "/home/antoine/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 204, in _to_rgba_no_colorcycle
        raise ValueError("RGBA values should be within 0-1 range")
    ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range
```

I've tried using different extensions than .ps, and all of them show the same error, except .png, which saves me a disgustingly awfull image, even when it's supposed to be 1200 dpi (I can't post you a link to the saved image as I do not have enough reputation, sorry).

I've also tried doing a "clean path" with os.path.join, but it changed nothing, so I reverted back to the syntax which used to work on the previous version.

I know my code is most likely suboptimal, but I'm learning so it can't be helped ...

Do you have any clues on how to solve this ?

EDIT : Added the minimal, complete and verifiable example :

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]]

    def plotAttempt():
        plt.errorbar(data[0],data[1],data[2],0)
        path = '/home/PlotAttempt.ps'
        plt.savefig(path)
```

Calling plotAttempt() through the console gets me the same error log

Comment: I would guess that the error originates from partof the code which you don't show here. The highest chances of getting help here is by providing a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: I am wondering if you are not using ndarray for parameters that trouble the RGB converter when saving PostScript file. I would look into that first.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I just added the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, i really did not expect it not to work ...

Comment: The [mcve] you show produces [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCWAS.png) when I run it. There is no error shown.

Comment: So i ran my code through the console instead of doing it through pyzo and it seems to work, i guess the issue comes from pyzo ... Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a pyzo bug, the code worked just fine when I ran it through the console and after rebooting it also worked on pyzo.